# Laravel3: Eloquent/Fluent fails during UPDATE statement

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

```
$account = Account::where('account_id', '=', $account_id)->first();
$account->username = 'New_Username';
$account->password = 'Password';
$account->save();

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Does your table have an id column?

Comment: Nope. account_id as auto increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update an Eloquent model it will use the model's primary key.  The default primary key is `id`, you can change this by adding the following in your class:

```
public static $key = 'account_id';
```

Be warned that there are some hard-coded references to `id` in Laravel, so the best advise is still to use `id` as a primary key when designing your databases for Eloquent.

Reference: [laravel/database/eloquent/model.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/database/eloquent/model.php#L50)

Comment: I use id as primary key in my own databases, but it's a different database I'm working on and it contains. I don't want to clean up references right now, so I'll just stick with your solution.